# A càdlàg function $f: [0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$ has only a finite amount of jumps bigger than $1/n$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

**Statement**

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. A càdlàg function $f: [0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$ has only a finite amount of jumps $\Delta f_t=f_t-f_{t-}$ with $|\Delta f_t|\geq 1/n$

**Proof** (Reductio ad absurdum)

Suppose, there a infinitely many $t\in [0,T]$ with $|\Delta f_t|\geq 1/n$. Hence $\{t\in [0,T]: |\Delta f_t|\geq 1/n\}$ has an accumulation point $t^*$. Then, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a tuple $(t_1,t_2)$ with $t^*-\varepsilon<t_1<t_2<t^*$ or $t^*<t_1<t_2<t^*+\varepsilon$ with $|f_{t_2}-f_{t_1}|\geq 1/(2n)$. [...]

**Question**: Why does this tuple exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It helps to first write down the relevant definitions, and then slowly expand upon what they mean so as to slowly get closer and closer to our desired conclusion.**

Since $t^{*}$ is an accumulation point of $A=\{t \in [0,T] : |\Delta f_t|\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$, there is a sequence $(a_n)_n$ of points in $A$ such that $a_n \neq t^{*}$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = t^{*}$.

Now, given $\varepsilon > 0$ we can guarantee that there will exist $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - t^{*}|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq n_0$ due to convergence. Note that it could happen that $a_n > t^{*}$ or that $a_n < t^{*}$, with possibly different inequalities for each $n\geq n_0$ - this will become relevant for whether the tuple we find has values above or below $t^{*}$. However, we can convince ourselves that for sure there will be *an infinite number of $n$* satisfying the same inequality, be it $a_n > t^{*}$ or $a_n < t^{*}$. We will suppose without loss of generality that there is an infinite number of $a_n$ bigger than $t^{*}$, or equivalently that we have a subsequence that converges from above to $t^{*}$ - this corresponds to the case that out tuple will find values above $t^{*}$, but the other case is treated almost identically. Furthermore, so as not to use cumbersome notation, we will instead suppose without loss of generality that the entire sequence $(a_n)_n$ is greater than $t^{*}$. Combining all of what we know so far, if $n\geq n_0$ then $0\leq a_n - t^{*} < \varepsilon$.

Lastly, we want to convince ourselves that we can find at least two distinct members of $A$ that satisfy the inequality. As of now we don't know if $a_n \neq a_m$ for different values $n\neq m$ so we will have to make an argument as to why at least two different terms that satisfy the property exist. Lets fix $t_1 = a_{n_0}$, and $\varepsilon_1 = a_{n_0} - t^{*}=t_1 - t^{*}$ - note that $\varepsilon_1\in (0,\varepsilon)$. Once again, because of convergence we have that there exists $n_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - t^{*}| < \varepsilon_1$ for $n\geq n_1$. Now setting $t_2 = a_{n_1}$, we get our tuple, as we have that
$$
t_2 - t^{*} = |a_{n_1} - t^{*}| < \varepsilon_1 < \varepsilon
$$
and $t_2 < t_1$ as
$$
t_2 - t^{*} = |a_{n_1} - t^{*}| < \varepsilon_1 = t_1 - t^{*}
$$
which implies what you needed for the proof.